# Steam, missing 32bit libs but it won't install

Tags: 13.10, apt, acer, chromebook

Steam needs to install these additional packages:
`libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, `libc6:i386`

```
[sudo] password for user:
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  tzdata libdb1-compat locales libc-bin initscripts

Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-mesa-glx

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
Press return to continue:
```

When I type in `sudo apt-get update`:

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for user:
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.

When I type in sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
user@chrubuntu:~$
```

P.S. I'm a total newbie at ubuntu/linux

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using HTTPS mirrors (see the error about the missing method driver). You might want to switch to a non-HTTPS mirror (the default mirror is usually non-HTTPS), install `apt-transport-https` and then switch back to your HTTPS mirror. Then run `apt-get update` and try installing the other packages.